# How to redirect to https in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I've just purchased an SSL certificate for a Wordpress site and want people to go to https://www... rather than http://www..

I've read that you need to change the Change the WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) within the dashboard in Settings - General.

I also read that you need to add in a redirect within an .htaccess file with:

```html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.net/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Do I need to do both?

If yes, does the above code get placed within the default Wordpress .htaccess code or would it appear above it?

Thanks

Comment: If you're converting your whole website into SSL you could use the "WP Force SSL" plugin. Then update all image paths on your CSS with https or any other place where they are static. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-ssl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not much use at .htaccess rules, but I know that's not the rule I use.  In conjunction with changing the Wordpress Address and Site Address (as you point out), I change the default Wordpress .htaccess to

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

However if it's an existing site you are going to run into the issue that your database is riddled with content full of image links using the `http` protocol which will break your padlock in the browser. Rather than editing all the posts, I use this tool;

https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

(Most folk use it when transferring a WP site from one domain to another) and just rename all the images in the database by replacing all instances of `http://www.example.com` with `https://www.example.com`

Comment: Thanks. Within your .htaccess rules above, do I need to add the full domain name or do I just use the rules as above?

Sorry, just a newbie.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delayed reply. Just use it exactly as is, no need to put the domain in at all. :)

Answer (score 5):

try adding this on to your functions.php instead of changing something in to your .htaccess

```php
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_core', 50);
add_action('init', 'redirect_core', 50);
add_action('wp_loaded', 'redirect_core', 50);
function redirect_core(){
  if (!is_ssl()) {
    wp_redirect('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 301);
    exit();
  }
}
```

or refer to this plugin: [HTTP Redirect](https://github.com/vindecodex/wp-https-redirect/blob/master/https-redirect.php)

Comment: It works only in google chrome, does not work in opera , safari etc

Answer (score 0):

you can run `code` inside your `functions.php`

```
function redirectToHTTPS(){
 if($_SERVER['HTTPS']!="on"){
   $redirect= "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("Location:$redirect");   
}}
add_action('init','redirectToHTTPS');
```

You can also use code inside `.htaccess`

`RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`

Both works, but use ony one, not both.

Answer (score 0):

```
Put this code in .htaccess file 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```